# Jboss Múltiplos context-root apontando mesmo war

Tags: java, jboss

boa noite.

É possível eu configurar no Jboss vários context-root apontando para o mesmo war? Caso não seja possível no jboss, existe alguma forma de eu fazer isso?

Obrigado

Comment: Da uma olhadinha nesta resposta:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30875657/multiple-context-root-for-single-war-deployment-jboss-eap-6-1

Comment: Muito bom, mas não consegui configurar para Jboss 6, só no 7. Obrigado1

Answer (score 0):

Acho que é possível sim, acabei achando esse comando caso vc use o jboss 7+

Pin your application via jboss-web.xml to context-root path1 and add rewrite rule to standalone.xml as shown:

```
<virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="false">  
     <alias name="localhost"/> 
     <rewrite name="rule-1"  pattern="^/path1(.*)$" substitution="/path2/$1" flags="NC"/>
 </virtual-server>
```

Comment: Fiz uma POC com Jboss 7 e funcionou do jeito que eu quero, mas preciso para o Jboss 6 e tá difícil de achar.

Answer (score 0):

Senhores, no final consegui resolver seguindo a documentação abaixo:

http://jbossweb.jboss.org/modules/rewrite.html

Meu rewrite.properties ficou assim:

RewriteRule ^/path1(.*)$  /path2$1 [NC]